# Django filter queryset and get unique items

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset, django-filter

I am using Django and SqLite.

I have this  model  table:

```
class TestPROD(models.Model):
    prodID    = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    ProdDate  = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Price1    = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3,default=0)
    Price2    = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3,default=0)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author    = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.prodID
    def get_Total(self):
        TotPRC =self.Price1 +self.Price2
        return round(TotPRC, 2) 
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('Custom', args=[self.prodID])
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-TestDate',)
```

in my data base I have many rows which contains duplicated items for example  `prodID` HP or Lenovo have 1000 or more rows.

my question is how to filter the data and give me only the last ProdDate  of the product HP and so the last item for Lenovo and one.

in my views.py I tried many solution but I din't get the good results

```
def welltests(request):
        testprodms = TestPROD.objects.annotate(latest_test_date=('prodID')).order_by('-ProdDate').distinct()
        return render(request, 'Home/AllProd.html', {'testprodms': testprodms})
```

this will gives my all the data (50000 rows) but organized by product.

the unique `prodID` in my database is about 600.
so  I need 600 rows of different product with the last `ProdDate`

then I tried this and many other but not working;

```
def welltests(request):
    testprodms = TestPROD.objects.order_by().values_list('prodID', flat=True).distinct()
    return render(request, 'Home/AllProd.html', {'testprodms': testprodms})
```

this gives me the number of my products but with no other data in my HTML page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many solutions that I want to get a solution in one line but I wasn't able to get. sorry, so I get solved this using 3 lines.

```
def welltests(request):
    testprodms = TestPROD.objects.order_by().values_list('prodID', flat=True).distinct()
    AllProdcts = TestPROD.objects.all()
    listtests  =  [AllProdcts.filter(prodID__exact=prodtest).first() for prodtest in testprodms]
    return render(request, 'Home/AllProd.html', {'testprodms': listtests})
```